# How to convert string 'yyyy-mm-dd' to date format in presto sql

Tags: date, presto

In presto SQL, the date is saved as a string like '2020-06-10'. I want to convert into a date format (yyyy-mm-dd)

This is how I did it:

```
select date_format(date_parse('2020-06-10', '%Y-%m-%d'),'%Y-%m-%d')
```

First I convert string to a timestamp format, then convert the new timestamp to date_format.

My question is that is there a function such that I convert only once?

For example

```
date_parse(string, format, expect_out_put_time_format)
```

Comment: There is no such function. We need to cast type first and then format it.

Comment: Gotcha.  Piotr's comment saved me a few keystrokes.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62497227/13785056


select date_format(date('2020-06-10'),'%Y-%m-%d')

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`date`](https://prestosql.io/docs/current/functions/datetime.html#date) function, which is a shortcut for `CAST(x AS date)`.

```
presto> SELECT date('2020-06-10');
   _col0
------------
 2020-06-10
```

Comment: I tried with SELECT date('2020-06-10')  </n> I got the **June 10, 2020, 12:00 AM** 
but I save some key-stokes, my simplified version is <n/>

`select date_format(date('2020-06-10'),'%Y-%m-%d')`

Comment: `June 10, 2020, 12:00 AM` -- this is probably something produced by your application when rendering `date` values. If you want to end up with a varchar value, it seems you do not need any conversion at all, do you?